# Why designers buy the UI kit for designers?

Tags: design-system

There are many design systems available online noways, but I am getting confused - what was the purpose of buying a designer system for the designers.

Why designers buy the UI kit instead of making or building their UI kit?
How can it be helpful for the organization and designers?
Is it help the UX designer to focus more on the solution instead of crafting the interface?

If you ever buy any design system, please share your experience.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are more talking about the UIKits than Design System. UIKit is one of the important items of Design System.

Design System mainly consists of

1. Design Principles
2. UIKits
3. Style Guide
4. Documentation

If the team is designing some app and they find some available UIKits resemble then they should use the existing and then build on top of it otherwise design a fresh UIKit which fits to their project need.

Comment: Nice answer, but no. 5 is "the font end codebase", no? Otherwise the dev team is free to ignore it all and the "system" only exists in the realm of those who don't write code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a multitude of design systems that exist today, that is true. However, the reasoning behind each of their existence depends on context.

There are many that exist as simple boiler plates to start from. Examples that come to mind are. These can range from simple UI kits, to a bit more advanced "design systems" (my reasoning for quotes will be addressed below).

- https://www.untitledui.com/
- [www.setproduct.com](http://www.setproduct.com) (multiple kits/systems)
- [www.uiprep.com](http://www.uiprep.com)
- [www.cabanaforfigma.com](http://www.cabanaforfigma.com)

Often, these exist to be customized and give you an easier starting point. They may also teach less experienced design tool users best practices when it comes to building a design system (how to best use symbols, libraries, components, etc.).

Then there are design systems tied a company or larger project. Some of these may be open source, some may not. They may be leveraged by other companies, teams and users to improve their own design systems.

- https://designsystemsrepo.com/design-systems/
- https://design-systems.io/

The difference between these two examples is important. It's the reason I used quotes above in my response. A design system should be created in the context of your organization, product and users. It should explain how to use it, why you made the decisions you made and be much more than a simple UI Kit. That is what makes it most valuable to those leveraging the system within a specific product. When conventions and guidelines exist, teams can more easily focus on other aspects of problem solving.

Because of this, no two design systems will be the same. Sure, they will share similarities, but because each product will encompass different users needs and business needs, the systems as a whole can be dramatically different. This is why most design systems are built from scratch...or use some sort of starter template and then are heavily altered.

Answer (score -1):

I would advise you to read the Atomic Design book. On the last chapters you a lot of information regarding your question.

Comment: Could you copy and paste some of the relevant information?

Comment: Please don't post answers to questions that don't answer the question.